# Flutter Web with Authorization Code Flow - working example wanted

Tags: flutter, dart, oauth-2.0, auth0, flutter-web

I am trying to get a Flutter v2 application working for Android, iOS and Web.  I have user logins working successfully, integrating with Auth0 using the Authorization Code Flow.

However, for the web version I have tried several libraries and guides. But I haven't been able to get it working and can't find a full working example.

Libraries and guides I've tried:

- https://pub.dev/packages/openid_client
- https://pub.dev/packages/simple_auth
- https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_appauth/issues/70
- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appauth
- https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2
- https://robinjanke1.medium.com/oauth2-with-flutter-web-e7a2b0dac7f3

Are there any example working applications I could use as template/starting point?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/Concerti-IO/openidconnect_flutter It's from the third link you gave

Comment: I've provided a quick explanation about the web Authenticator. It works only on the implicit flow. So far I could not find any Authorization flow on the web. It appears that one has to write his own Authenticator class.  [More Info Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74426666/returning-null-credentials-when-authenticating-flutter-web-app-with-keycloak-usi) Let me know if you learned anything extra besides what I've shared. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**1. Example #1 with package: [flutter_web_auth: ^0.4.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_auth/example)**

*example/lib/main.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io' show HttpServer;

import 'package:flutter_web_auth/flutter_web_auth.dart';

const html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Grant Access to Flutter</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

    main {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      min-height: 100vh;
      font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,Apple Color Emoji,Segoe UI Emoji,Segoe UI Symbol;
    }

    #icon {
      font-size: 96pt;
    }

    #text {
      padding: 2em;
      max-width: 260px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    #button a {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 6px 12px;
      color: white;
      border: 1px solid rgba(27,31,35,.2);
      border-radius: 3px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, #34d058 0%, #22863a 90%);
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 600;
    }

    #button a:active {
      background-color: #279f43;
      background-image: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div id="icon">&#x1F3C7;</div>
    <div id="text">Press the button below to sign in using your Localtest.me account.</div>
    <div id="button"><a href="foobar://success?code=1337">Sign in</a></div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
""";

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _status = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startServer();
  }

  Future<void> startServer() async {
    final server = await HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', 43823);

    server.listen((req) async {
      setState(() { _status = 'Received request!'; });

      req.response.headers.add('Content-Type', 'text/html');
      req.response.write(html);
      req.response.close();
    });
  }

  void authenticate() async {
    final url = 'http://localtest.me:43823/';
    final callbackUrlScheme = 'foobar';

    try {
      final result = await FlutterWebAuth.authenticate(url: url, callbackUrlScheme: callbackUrlScheme);
      setState(() { _status = 'Got result: $result'; });
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      setState(() { _status = 'Got error: $e'; });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Web Auth example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Status: $_status\n'),
              const SizedBox(height: 80),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Authenticate'),
                onPressed: () { this.authenticate(); },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**2. Example #2 with package: [openidconnect](https://pub.dev/packages/openidconnect)**

*example/lib/main.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:openidconnect_example/choose.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

//Credentials gathered from the playground
//login: dull-moth@example.com
//password: Yawning-Octopus-58

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ChoosePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The second example shows nothing relevant.