# Returning null credentials when authenticating flutter web app with keycloak using openid_client

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, keycloak, openid-connect

I use the flutter [openid_client](https://pub.dev/packages/openid_client) package to integrate keycloak auth with a flutter web app. All the flow is successful (when the login button is clicked the app redirects to the keycloak login page and after entering the credentials it redirects back to my app, also the keycloak admin console shows a user after I log in) but the problem is returning null credentials. Can't access credentials, access token, id token, etc... Here is my code, can anyone help me?

```
Future authenticate(Uri uri, String clientId, List<String> scopes) async {   
    
    // create the client
    var issuer = await Issuer.discover(uri);
    var client = new Client(issuer, clientId);
    
    // create an authenticator
    var authenticator = new Authenticator(client, scopes: scopes);
    
    // get the credential
    var c = await authenticator.credential;
    
    if (c==null) {
      // starts the authentication
      authenticator.authorize(); // this will redirect the browser
    } else {
      // return the user info
      return await c.getUserInfo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, i got the exact same problem, did you find the solution ?

Comment: Not yet. I used [flutter_web_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_auth) package instead of this.

Comment: I provided an answer explaining what happens on the web. Did you manage to make any progress on the web side?

Answer (score 0):

- **openid_client web example uses implicit flow** - Keycloak is configured to accept only authorization code flow while the `openid_client` flutter web example is built around the implicit flow. The implicit flow is no longer recommended. This was the first issue I had after replicating the example in my app. I tried as well to connect to keycloak via the demo page. It had the same issue. When tapping on login we got redirected to keycloak but then we got redirected back again to the app with no credentials (Id token) being delivered. Looking at the logs in podman I could see the following message `"Client is not allowed to initiate browser login with given response_type. Implicit flow is disabled for the client."` Using this information I now know that we need to adjust the code on the FE `openid_client` side. We have to figure out how to initialize the authorization code flow not the implicit flow.
- **Web Authenticator is Stuck on implicit flow** - It appears that the readme provides a sample for android/ios. Currently the Authenticator that openid_client provides for the browser supports only the implicit flow as far as I can see from the source code. I'm trying to figure out if I can write my own `Authenticator` that can support authorization flow on the web. I was hopping to find this as part of the library. No clear docs/reason are provided as to why implicit flow is used on the web as long as it is currently deprecated and advised against.
- **The native Authenticator uses a server** - This authenticator uses a local http server to listen for the redirect from the authorization server. In other words don't even think you could use the native Authenticator do implement authorisation code flow on web.  You'd have to build your own, I don't think the maintainers are rushing to update the web one. As long as you know wha to do should not be "that hard". There are plenty of code samples in the source code.
- **ID Token not persisted on web** - From web Authenticator doc comment: The state is not persisted in the browser, so the user will have to sign in again after a page refresh.