# how to use authorization code flow (keycloak) in a flutter web project

Tags: flutter, authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

**How to implement authorization code flow in a Flutter app using openid_client?
**
I am developing a Flutter app that needs to authenticate users with Keycloak using the authorization code flow. I have tried using the openid_client package, but I am facing some issues with it.

First of all, there are not many resources or examples on how to use this package with Flutter web. The documentation is very sparse and does not explain how to handle the redirect URI, the state parameter, or the code verifier.

Secondly, when I try to integrate it with my app, it gets stuck in a loop of opening Keycloak login pages.

I have also tried other packages like flutter_appauth and oauth2_client, but they either do not support Flutter web or have similar problems.

Does anyone know how to properly implement authorization code flow in a Flutter app using openid_client or any other package? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

keycloak configuration:
Access Type: public
Standard Flow Enabled: ON
Valid Redirect URIs: http://localhost:54841/

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74426666/returning-null-credentials-when-authenticating-flutter-web-app-with-keycloak-usi